# Unusual behaviour about Hot and Cold comments

Tags: discussion, comments

As far as I know comments with more up-votes appear in a color with more red density (hotter color). But today I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/1841194) that has a couple of comments at its below and one of them has 222 number of up-votes and it's purely black, also this post has another comment with 16 up-votes that is relatively red (hot).

Now I'd want to know is there a rule or story behind of this or something like bug happened?

[image]